# Objective C Game Geometry question

Tags: objective-c, xcode, geometry, trigonometry

I'm creating simple game and reached the point where I feel helpless. I was good in geometry but it was long time back in school, now trying to refresh my mind.

Let's say i have iPad screen. Object's xy position at one given point of time and xy position at another point of time stored in 2 variables .

Question:
how to find the third position of the object at the end of the screen being given previous 2 position, considering the object moves in the same direction (line) from point 1 to point 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Let us have that `v1` and `v2` are the vectors representing the two points. Let `t0` be the time between the two points. Let `t` be the current time.

Then our location vector `v3` is given by `v3 = v1 + (v2 - v1)t/t0`

Comment: How are you going to deal with time in such a situation?

Comment: Time doesn't concern me that much, I have CADisplayLink *theTimer;

Comment: So how do you access x and y of v3 at certain point of time in object c.

Comment: @Rouslan Karimov I don't program in Objective C and all that but I would assume your Point or Vector class lets you get x and y...

Answer (score -1):

If the object is moving in the same direction and you have an horizontal line, the next position given x and y would be

```
x+1, y
```

If the object is moving in the same direction in a vertical line it would be

```
x, y+1
```

If the object is moving in a diagonal up-right

```
x+1,y+1
```

diagonal down-right

```
x+1, y+1
```

diagonal down-left

```
x-1, y-1
```

diagonal up-left

```
x-1, y+1
```

So something general would be :

```
newPosition = (x+1,y) //if you wish to move forward to the right, try to handle all    
                        cases
```

All the cases above work if the object is moving forward, if it is moving backwards just change the + by - . Basically think of the object as moving in a cartesian coordinate system, where x is horizontal and y is vertical.

I think you can get the idea out of this three cases ;)

Comment: this does not address all possible cases.

Comment: my object moves by touch. The above approach doesn't solve my problem.What if my first point 100x 100y and second 200x 458y, given approach won't work.  I'm sure there is some basic trigonometry function can sort it. Any ideas?